# Unable to import data from Hdfs to Hbase using importtsv

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bulk-load

I moved tab delimited file into hdfs now was trying to move it to hbase.
Below is my importtsv command

```
  bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf:ok,cf:ek,cf:rk,cf:rsk,cf:pdk,cf:pmk,cf:omk,cf:sok,cf:sdk,cf:cdk,cf:q,cf:uc,cf:up,cf:usp,cf:gm,cf:st,cf:gp -Dimporttsv.skip.bad.lines=false 'sales_fact' hdfs://localhost:54310/my/file.txt
```

it is trying to read a jar from location which doesnt exists.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/home/elijah/Downloads/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1072)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1064)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1064)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:265)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:301)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:389)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv.run(ImportTsv.java:738)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv.main(ImportTsv.java:747)
```

I am not getting why it has mixed up hdfs and local dir path into one.
hdfs://localhost:54310/home/elijah/Downloads/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar

User who is running import job has full access to hbase lib on local directory.

Comment: just check my answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: if you are okay with answer! please care to vote-up! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see `-libjars` option is missing....You can use `-libjars` option below is example usage :

```
hadoop jar \
hbase-server-0.98.6-cdh5.2.1.jar \
importtsv \
-libjars /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.1-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.12/jars/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar \
-Dimporttsv.separator=, -Dimporttsv.bulk.output=output \
-Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,f:count wordcount \
word_count.csv
```

You can also do something like this:-

```
# export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`./hbase classpath`
```

#### One of the jar which was missing i.e hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar will be hbase classpath. and should work in this case.